# How to Keep scales free with limiting scale_y_sqrt in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
 ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
 geom_point() +
 facet_wrap(vars(class), scales = "free")
```

We see that subcompact exceed 40 so I want to better visualize using scale_y_sqrt(limits = c(12,40))

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(vars(class), scales = "free")+scale_y_sqrt(limits = 
c(12,40))
```

now the problem is all panel are limited to 12 and 40. I want to keep the scale free but in case, if some panels exceed 40, then limit to 30. For example the panels of suv and minivan should not be changed as the maximum in y axis is 24 or 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the `ggh4x` package which via `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` allows to individually set the positional scales individually for each panel.

If you just want to set the scale for one class you could e.g. do

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(class), scales = "free")

p +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    y = class == "subcompact" ~ scale_y_sqrt(limits = c(12, 40))
  )
```

[image]

Or is you want to set the scales for all panels based on a condition you could do:

```r
scales_y <- mpg |>
  split(~class) |>
  lapply(
    \(x) {
      if (max(x$hwy) > 30) scale_y_sqrt(limits = c(12, 40))
    }
  )

p +
  facetted_pos_scales(y = scales_y)
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks, that works. I want to add another condition  if (max(x$hwy) < 25) scale_y_sqrt(limits = c(10, 26)),, so I have 2 conditions. but it affects all other panels.

Comment: if we have 2 conidtions, It seems that the last condition dominate.

Comment: What do you expect? That's how an `if` works. If you use an `if` and then a second `if` the first will of course have no effect. Instead, you need an `if-else` if you want to set the scale for the panels based on multiple conditions.